# What does the value x signify in the solution?

Tags: c++, algorithm, logic

Problem Statement::

> Given a string 's' consisting of upper case alphabets, i.e. from 'A' to 'Z'. Your task is to find how many strings 't' with length equal to that of 's', also consisting of upper case alphabets are there satisfying the following conditions:
>
> - String 't' is lexicographical larger than string 's'.
> - When you write both 's' and 't' in the reverse order, 't' is still lexicographical larger than 's'.
>
> Find out number of such strings 't'. As the answer could be very large, take modulo 10^9 + 7.

Solution:::

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define m 1000000007

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    string s;cin>>s;
    long long int x=0,ans=0;
    int n=s.size();
    for(int i=0;i<n; i++){
        ans+=((x+1)%m)*('Z'-s[i]);
        x= ((26*x)%m)+('Z'-s[i]);
    }
    cout<<ans%m;
    return 0;
}
```

I am unable to get the significance of the variable `x`.
What does it actually represent?

Comment: The code is running perfectly fine.But i am unable to get the significance of the variable x.What it actually represents?

Comment: Working on the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Let `D[i]` be `'Z'-s[i]` - the number of possible characters that compare greater than `s[i]` (using zero-based indexing throughout).

Let `X[i]` be the number of strings of length `i` that are lexicographically greater than `s`. Obviously, `X[0] == 0` - an empty string is less than any other string. For a string of length `i+1` to be greater than `s`, one of two conditions must be true:

- its prefix of length `i` is greater than `s`, and the last character can be anything. There are `X[i]*26` such strings.
- its prefix of length `i` is exactly equal to the corresponding prefix of `s`, and the last character is greater than `s[i]`. There are `D[i]` such strings.

Putting this together, `X[i+1] = X[i]*26 + D[i]`.

In the program, the variable `x` represents the sequence `X` - it's equal to `X[i]` at the beginning of the loop iteration, and is updated to `X[i+1]` at the end; in both cases, reduced modulo `m` to avoid overflow.

---

Now, how does this contribute to the answer? Consider a string `t` that satisfies the two conditions in the problem statement. Let `k` be the last (rightmost) position where `t[k] > s[k]`; for all positions `z > k`, `t[z] == s[z]`. This position `k` must exist, for `reverse(t) > reverse(s)` to hold. In other words, when `s` and `t` are read backwards, they may have a few (possibly zero) characters in common, followed by a character from `t` being greater than a character from `s`.

Further, the prefix of `t` of length `k` must be greater than or equal to the corresponding prefix of `s`, for `t > s` to hold. In other words, when `s` and `t` are read forward, either all characters before `k` are equal, or there's some earlier character in `t` that's greater than the corresponding character in `s`.

Let `Y[k]` be the number of strings that a) satisfy the conditions of the problem, and b) have `k` as the rightmost position at which `t` and `s` differ; that is, the rightmost position where `t[k] > s[k]`. It is easy to see that `Y[k] = (X[k] + 1) * D[k]`. Indeed, there are `X[k]+1` possible prefixes that are greater than (`X[k]`) or equal to (`1`) the corresponding prefix of `s`. Any of them can be followed by any of `D[k]` characters that are greater than `s[k]`, and then followed by one suffix that's exactly equal to the corresponding suffix of `s`.

Finally, the total number of strings `t` that satisfy the conditions of the problem is the sum of `Y[i]` over all positions `i`.

In the program, the variable `ans` accumulates the sum of `Y[i]`, reduced modulo `m` to avoid overflow.

Comment: Your answer is a bit hard to understand. Consider adding examples to explain different points. You could also add headings like Notation, Solution, Code etc to make it more understandable.